# Tratando elementos Json com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

estou com um código aqui, onde eu preciso pegar elementos de um Json, e apresentar na tela com um botao de busca, no codigo ele percorre o json com um foreach, mais pra ele percorrer eu faço um if, pra ele comparar o que eu digitei na linha, com o atributo porem ele entende como se o que eu digitei na linha estivesse errado
SEGUE O CODIGO.

```
 function fazGet(url) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open("GET", url, false)
        request.send()
        return request.responseText
    }

    function crialinha(d) {
        linha = document.createElement("tr");
        tdNMae = document.createElement("td")
        tdNMae.innerHTML = d.NomeMae
        linha.appendChild(tdNMae)





        return linha;



    }


    function main() {

        let data = fazGet("http://10.45.0.22/WebService1.asmx/LocalizaOperadora?Cidade=BRUMADINHO");

        let usuarios = data


        var resultadoEspaco = usuarios.split("[");
        let teste = resultadoEspaco[1]


        var resultadoEspaco2 = teste.split("]");
        let teste2 = resultadoEspaco2[0]

        teste2.replace("\"", " ")
        let a = teste2
        let b = "["
        let c = "]"
        b += a
        b += c
        let d = JSON.parse(b)
        console.log(d)
        console.log(d[0].NomeMae)




        let tabela = document.getElementById("tabela")



        /* Foreach para montar tabela 
         d.forEach(element => {
              let linha = crialinha(element);
              tabela.appendChild(linha);



          }); */
        //variavel buscar CEP
        let CEP = document.getElementById("cep")

        //variavel apresentar resultado
        var retorno = document.getElementById("retorno")
        d.forEach(element => {

            if (CEP === d.NomeMae) {
                let linha = crialinha(element);
                retorno = tabela.appendChild(linha);

                return;

            }
        });
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="tabela" border="1">

    </table>
    <input type="text" id="cep" placeholder="Digite CEP">
    <input type="button" onclick="main()" value="buscar">
    <label for="" id="retorno"></label>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Huum, tu tá fazendo uma comparação === entre o cep e a variável que recebeu o jason, mais especificamente esse campo do nome, mas no caso, quais as tipagens dos dois? Porque let cep e d.NomeMae podem estar em tipos diferentes, se estiverem o === pode dar como errado mesmo que o conteúdo seja o mesmo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esse erro eu ja resolvi, na verdade é outra questão, eu tinha que buscar no cep um  getElementById("cep").value; agora eu so preciso retornar somente os dados correspondentes ao que eu digitar la